# Sound Not Working on Ubuntu 18.04.5

Tags: 18.04, sound

Recently, the sound has stopped working on my DELL Latitude 3510 laptop (Ubuntu version 18.04.5). As a result of a lag, I had to shut it down a few hours ago. After restarting it, however, the sound card was suddenly not recognized anymore; “Dummy Output” was the only recognized device. After searching through this forum and a few other places, I noticed some people had already had the same problem. As I am not tech-savvy in the slightest, however, I spent quite a bit of time copying and pasting terminal lines, only to reboot and realize nothing had changed. As most of the questions were rather old, I thought they might be outdated or not applicable to my computer for whatever reason, and so I ultimately decided to ask this question directly.

I apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge; I have no idea what is important in these types of problems, and I am, of course, happy to provide any additional information should the need arise. As of now, however, I am thoroughly confused and in a bit of a bad mood – are there any steps I should take?

Comment: What's the model of your sound adapter?  You might want to use that as a search term here and elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to AskUbuntu!

To fix this, two configuration files need to be updated:

1. Open a terminal
2. Open the base configuration file:
   `sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
3. Add this line to the bottom of the file:
   `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0`
4. Save and close the file
5. Open the block configuration file:
   `sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
6. Add this to the bottom of the file:
   `blacklist snd_soc_skl`
7. Save and close the file
8. Reboot

This should solve your problem